# How can i create custom price list section in Shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I'd like to create a pricelist session in my theme on Shopify.
The section should include:
A title
A subtitle
3 blocks with content inside
And the blocks should be editable in the theme customization.

I want something like this:
[pricelist-section-image.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJWts.jpg)

Thanks for any help

Comment: I think you need to be started with liquid code and HTML & CSS for it [link](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid)

Comment: okay. i need to learn liquid then